# Get filesize from IdTCPClient1

Tags: delphi, file-handling, delphi-xe7

I want to get filesize, but after receiving file lose 4 bytes. Because of what is happening and how to fix it?

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPClient1Connected(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  FPath, FName: String;
begin
  FPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Downloads';
  FName := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn;

  if not DirectoryExists(FPath) then ForceDirectories(FPath);

  FS := TFileStream.Create(FPath + '\' + ExtractFileName(FName), fmCreate);
  try
    CProgressBar.Max := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLongInt(); // Proble here. Without thats ok
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStream(FS, -1, True);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FS);
  end;

  IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;

  CLabel.Caption := 'File received';
end;
```

Comment: Could it be meta-data that's lost? After receiving the file does it still works or contains all the data?

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing how the file data is being sent in the first place. You are reading the first 4 bytes and interpretting them as the file size.  And you are telling `ReadStream()` to keep reading until a disconnect occurs, regardless of the size. Does the server actually send a 4byte size before sending the actual file? Based on your description, I suspect not. What is the actual protocol being used?

Comment: That is what I have in mind does not work, you can not do that. File size should be sent separately :)

Answer (score 0):

File size should be sent separately